# Does MyGet.org have an API to retrieve number of downloads?

Tags: myget

We are considering using MyGet.org to host our nuget packages. We'd like to be able to get some insight to how much these packages are being used. Does MyGet have an API so we can track number of downloads or other usage statistics?